# Mixed application implementing access rules

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, webforms

I have mixed web application web forms & mvc2.
At the moment i have set up access to directories for webforms using active directory permitions.
How ever as we enhancing our system we have to consider to apply roles to diferent pages, in order to restrict certain areas from users.

I know i can restrict by roles controllers in mvc as:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "DefaultUser")]
```

What will be the best way to implement role provider for old web forms?

thank you for your comments/answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like below in your page's OnInit event.

```
   if (!System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole("DefaultUser"))
        System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

There is also another path through web.config under configuration -> location

```
<location path="urltoyoursecurepage.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="DefaultUser" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Though i wouldn't prefer this type of configuration mess over the former.